# ASP.NET MVC - Reuse complex rendering logic

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm trying to render panels ( that are much like thumbnails or web parts) in asp.net mvc with the razor view engine, and its easy enough when I have to render them all at once, since I got a single view and all the rendering logic is there.

But my problems began when I had to add a new panel to the panel group, here's my view:

```
@model IEnumerable<FonteDeNoticia>
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-lg-8">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input id="txtUrl" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Url">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button id="btnAdicionarUrl" class="btn btn-default" type="button">Add</button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="fontesDeNoticia" class="row-fluid">            
    @foreach (var fonte in Model)
    {
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-lg-4">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title"><a href="@fonte.Link" target="_new">@fonte.Nome <span class="badge badge-info">42</span></a><span class="iconeClicavel"><a><i class="icon-remove pull-right"></i></a></span><span class="iconeClicavel"><a><i class="icon-gear pull-right"></i></a></span></h3>
                </div>
                <ul class="list-group">
                    @foreach (var noticia in fonte.Noticias.Take(3))
                    {
                        <li class="list-group-item">
                            <a class="linkDeNoticia" href="@noticia.Link" target="_new">@noticia.Titulo</a>
                            <small class="dataDeNoticia">- @noticia.DataDePublicacao</small>
                        </li>
                    }
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

So I came to realize that something needed to change... I tried to use DisplayForModel, but the way that I render the panels matter a lot, and I couldn't make it work.

Then I thought about rendering the foreach as a partial view in a for loop, but I think that the performance of that must be horrible!

Any ideas on this?

Comment: Do you want to add a panel dynamically to the page?

Comment: Look if you want to add something dynamically you have to use ajax.. so you will update or replace a part of your page only. Or you want to rerender your page completely?

Comment: I want to add the panel dynamically yeah, I tried to make an action that returns a single panel, but I couldn't find a way to 'attach' it to the existing ones, I know I can get the information that I need on the success callback, but I need that foreach logic.

Comment: Just to make it a bit more clear, that button above the first foreach is meant to add a new panel to the page, but when that happends I need to make sure that this new panel goes through the rendering logic.

Comment: put the code in partial View page and render them from Html.Partial or RenderPartial

Answer (score 0):

render Partial view in a loop is not that bad. since `DisplayForModel` internally use Html.Partial. I've implemented a complex plug-ins system this way.

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    @if (Model.FooterAreaPlugins != null && Model.FooterAreaPlugins.Count != 0)
    {
        <div id="@Model.ID-plugInGridFooterArea">
            @foreach (var item in @Model.FooterAreaPlugins)
            {
                @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/Module.cshtml", item);
            }
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

when my app grown larger at least 100+ `Html.Partial` (and some `Html.Action`) invoked to render many different models for a single page and there are no significant performance drop.